# postgresql odbc driver running extra queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I am using PostgreSQL as my backend database. I am running query from my application through PostgreSQL odbc driver(Unicode x64). When I see PostgreSQL log it actually running two queries.

The query which I execute:

```
2015-04-03 16:54:24 IST00000LOG:  statement: 
select n.nspname, c.relname, a.attname, a.atttypid, t.typname, a.attnum, a.attlen, a.atttypmod, a.attnotnull, c.relhasrules, c.relkind, c.oid, pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), case t.typtype when 'd' then t.typbasetype else 0 end, t.typtypmod, c.relhasoids from (((pg_catalog.pg_class c inner join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace and c.oid = 274738) inner join pg_catalog.pg_attribute a on (not a.attisdropped) and a.attnum > 0 and a.attrelid = c.oid) inner join pg_catalog.pg_type t on t.oid = a.atttypid) left outer join pg_attrdef d on a.atthasdef and d.adrelid = a.attrelid and d.adnum = a.attnum order by n.nspname, c.relname, attnum
```

I am using postgresql 9.3.5 with postgres-odbc driver 9.03.02.00

For each query I run the PostgreSQL running 2nd query every time.

how can I disable this 2nd query from running.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

That second query is most likely being generated by your framework, and it is being used to get the metadata about the result set.  More than likely to do automatic casting of data.   In order to stop its generation you will need to consult the framework you are using and see if there is anyway to stop it. But please note, if it is possible to disable that, there is a good chance that it will break something as you will no longer have metadata about the result sets.